# Failed to verify a dsawithSha1 signed message against a DSA public key in m2crypto

Tags: python, m2crypto

I'm trying to verify a signed message using a x509 certificate holding a dsa public key.
The x509 certificate was provided by an SAP System in PKCS7 encoding and after converting in PEM with openssl I'm able to read the contents (openssl x509 -in sapcert.pem -inform pem -text)
It holds a public key in dsaEncryption, showing me the DSA parameters y(pub), p, q and g.

Because I did not found a DSA implementation in M2Crypto x509 class, I tried to build the DSA public key by myself. Therefor I patched MyCrypto, (see: [How do I create a M2Crypto DSA object given parameters and key values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027196/how-do-i-create-a-m2crypto-dsa-object-given-parameters-and-key-values)), compilied it and got a new function DSA.pub_key_from_params(p,q,g,y) to build my DSA public-key using the parameters found in the certificate.
Until this point everything works fine. (The unittest although ran without errors).

In the second step I recieve the signedMessage (named seckey) as an URL parameter and after decoding it (base64) I got an proper DER string I'm able to read with openssl (openssl ans1parse -in seckey -inform der).
In the output from openssl I can see the signed messageDigest, which is exactly the SHA1 encoded messagedigest I try to verify (so I can be sure the signedMessage was provided properly). Although I can see a dsaWithSHA1 signature string which seems to hold the r and s values needing for verify an dsa signed message (see: [M2Crypto: verifying DSA signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454523/m2crypto-verifying-dsa-signatures))

At this point I stuck in my attempts to verify the signedMessage for a couple of days now and I hope there is a crytographic-expert out there who can help me. I tried and googled a lot, tried the pyCrypto lib instead, all without success.

I tried to pass the SHA1 MessageDigest and the r and s values to the M2Crypto.DSA.verify function but due it fails I think I either had to pass the signedMessage or parts of it.
(in a Java forum I found some posts about verifying signedMessages provided by SAP and theres somewhat about calculating the signature over "the DER encoding
of the signed attributes." ?)

Here's my sample code:

```
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-

import M2Crypto
import urllib
import base64
from Crypto.Util import asn1
from M2Crypto import m2
import sha

# the certificate
cert = """subject=/C=DE/O=SAP Trust Community/OU=SAP Web AS/OU=I0020154766/CN=RE2
issuer=/C=DE/O=SAP Trust Community/OU=SAP Web AS/OU=I0020154766/CN=RE2
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

"""
f = open('sapcert.pem', 'w')
f.write(cert)
f.close()

# now you can see it content with openssl
# openssl x509 -in sapcert.pem -inform pem -text


# this is the signedMessage
secKey = "MIIBSwYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIBPDCCATgCAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMAsGCSqGSIb3DQEHATGCARcwggETAgEBMGkwZDELMAkGA1UEBhMCREUxHDAaBgNVBAoTE1NBUCBUcnVzdCBDb21tdW5pdHkxEzARBgNVBAsTClNBUCBXZWIgQVMxFDASBgNVBAsTC0kwMDIwMTU0NzY2MQwwCgYDVQQDEwNSRTICAQAwCQYFKw4DAhoFAKBdMBgGCSqGSIb3DQEJAzELBgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwHAYJKoZIhvcNAQkFMQ8XDTExMDUyNjE1MzAyNVowIwYJKoZIhvcNAQkEMRYEFPelg4iVtaKORpuFxUvgo23Du7%2BtMAkGByqGSM44BAMELjAsAhQ46oCNmzZArb5yOFSYGY0hWu8dZwIUT35hPccJ6B9HIsOE0u8LwYZaFNk%3D"
secKey = urllib.unquote(secKey)
secKey64 = base64.b64decode(secKey)
# now you can save it as a DER encoded file
f = open('seckey.der', 'wb')
f.write(secKey64)
f.close()
# you can pass it to openssl to see the the content
# openssl asn1parse -in seckey.der -inform der


# here is the sha1 encoded messagedigest I had to verify
hashstr = "ZS4DDB9616BA031C40E1008003AC100097dCN%3DRE2,OU%3DI0020154766,OU%3DSAPWebAS,O%3DSAPTrustCommunity,C%3DDE20110526173025"
osha1=M2Crypto.EVP.MessageDigest('sha1')
osha1.update(hashstr)
sha1_md = osha1.digest()
print sha1_md.encode('hex')

# now i build a DSA key with the params found in the certificate

pub="8d5e9bfd28c3131310ff9a933e7a068bd0ed0e8b8aa52654b2f125c8c3a338c8fb9cfa22b00fb6e6f6bde2d73dd8210c77070798c72a8a93e091e9a9173eba12"
p="ffff31d41aa7e1ad3414aafd093c0f3ec931cb4cabc7b894e93e2fcdae305bddcca3677f2184d9340c45aa1ae6f9f214ac4a797f1229611989aca2f6a9109499"
q="dadcb17945beb5c7e39e6033af6f29979b85065f"
g="998cd74f31d8c2fa8a10ce3a16f417c82e4ef89227c2093b0da73b82a1809248424b568823856473d908131dc614b0f69b1e3ec89b8c43ca50e30cf81647c124"


pub1 = M2Crypto.m2.bn_to_mpi(M2Crypto.m2.hex_to_bn(pub))
p1 = M2Crypto.m2.bn_to_mpi(M2Crypto.m2.hex_to_bn(p))
q1 = M2Crypto.m2.bn_to_mpi(M2Crypto.m2.hex_to_bn(q))
g1 = M2Crypto.m2.bn_to_mpi(M2Crypto.m2.hex_to_bn(g))

# this function is available after patching und compiling M2Crypto
# https://bugzilla.osafoundation.org/attachment.cgi?id=5700
dsa1 = M2Crypto.DSA.pub_key_from_params(p1, q1, g1, pub1)
print dsa1.check_key()

# this seems to be the signature-values r and s in seckey.der
asn_hex = "302C021438EA808D9B3640ADBE72385498198D215AEF1D6702144F7E613DC709E81F4722C384D2EF0BC1865A14D9"

r = asn_hex[8:48]
s = asn_hex[52:]
r1 = M2Crypto.m2.bn_to_mpi(M2Crypto.m2.hex_to_bn(r))
s1 = M2Crypto.m2.bn_to_mpi(M2Crypto.m2.hex_to_bn(s))

# but this fails
v = dsa1.verify(sha1_md, r1, s1)
print v

# this too
sk = M2Crypto.m2.bn_to_mpi(M2Crypto.m2.bin_to_bn(secKey64))
v = dsa1.verify(sk, r1, s1)
print v
```

Is there anybody who knows how to do a proper dsawithsha1 signature verification? Please help!
best Regards,
Falko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you named `seckey64` in your sample code is actually a SignedData structure from [CMS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652).

It contains two "signed attributes", signing-time and message-digest. In order to verify this as a signature you need to follow the rules of the RFC that apply when at least one signed attribute is present.

In your case the message digest of the original data is contained in the message-digest attribute, so you would need to compare your computation with the attribute's value byte per byte first.

If these are equal, then you'd extract the signature value from the appropriate field of the SignerInfo structure. Finally your SHA-1 message digest that serves as the other input to the DSA signature verification will be computed over the raw encoding of the signed attributes of the SignerInfo. I'm not sure if M2Crypto has built-in support for SignedData (it's still often referred to as PKCS#7), but I guess [pyOpenSSL](http://pyopenssl.sourceforge.net/) should support it, so you could give it a try if M2Crypto leads you to a dead end.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry about my late response. I found a way verifying the signature using a openssl call to the new implemented cms function in openssl 1.0.0, so this works for me at the moment. If I have a lot more time I will try to find a more pythonic solution and I so your explanation and suggestions will be very useful for this. I will notify you if I found a way to do this pyOpenSSL or M2Crypto. Thanks a lot, Falko